# Частично закрасить фигуру swing

Tags: java, swing

Есть код отрисовки синего прямоугольника. В данном случае его полностью закрашивает синим.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ...

        Color color = new Color(1,0,0,0.0f);
        g2.setPaint(color);
        if (text.length() != 0 ){
            g2.draw(r);
            Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 15, width, height);
            g2.draw(r2D);
            g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
            g2.fill(r2D);
        }
    }
```

Есть ли возможность закрасить его допустим наполовину? (т.е. нижняя часть будет синей, а верхняя другого цвета, пусть зеленого). Или же проще будет рисовать 2 прямоугольника  один над другим (верхний - зеленый, а нижний - синий) и просто процент закрашенного регулировать при помощи высоты и координат каждого из прямоугольников?

Comment: Самый простой вариант нарисовать две фигуры и раскрашивать по отдельности. Можно создать класс в котором будут находиться обе фигуры и контролировать их с помощью класса. Ещё можно попробовать повозиться с градиентом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что в вашем случае проще будет рисовать 2 прямоугольника, сливающихся в один, с разными цветами:

```
  @Override
  public void init() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setForeground(Color.white);
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g2.setPaint(Color.gray);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 20;
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 100, 30));
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y+30, 100, 30));
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    g2.drawString("Один прямоугольник с двумя цветами", x, 250);
  }
```

Подправленный [**пример отсюда.**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/FillaRectangle2.htm)

Comment: Спасибо! должно подойти.

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример градиента:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.cyan, 200,
200, Color.red, false));
Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 15, width, height);
g2d.fill(r2D);
```

Попробуйте подобрать нужные вам значения.